"/bin/bash: wget: command not found" error in Jupyter notebook environment
I mainly use Google Colab, but Google Colab had a payment issue, so yesterday I tried to run the 100% same code in Jupyter Notebook.
My code is :
!pip install --upgrade mxnet
!pip install --upgrade gluoncv

!pip uninstall -y torch torchvision torchaudio torchtext

And when I tried install wget, just like this,
!wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tgz
!tar -xvfz Python-3.8.5.tgz
!Python-3.8.5/configure
!make
!sudo make install

this error popped up:
/bin/bash: wget: command not found
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'z'
/bin/bash: Python-3.8.5/configure: No such file or directory
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Password:

I couldn't understand why it doesn't work.
How can I fix this error? If anyone knows please help.

wget is not a built-in command of either Python or the shell; it has to be installed separately. configure would be a script that comes from the Python source code, which was not installed because wget was not found to download the Python source in the first place.

You may, however, have curl installed, in which case you should be able to simply replace wget with curl. (The command line may need to be adjusted to accommodate how curl works, though.)

In all of modern Jupyter, you'll have a better experience using %pip install.. and not !pip install ... when running install command inside active notebook files. It even works in Google Colab now, though years ago they rigged it so the reasons for the issues with the exclamation point in conjunction with pip wouldn't be in an issue in Colab. The modern magic variation added in 2019 is current best practice and ensures the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that is backing the active notebook. See more about the modern %pip install command ...

 here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Installing Python from source is itself not a great idea. There are packaging systems that will give you precompiled interpreters for MacOS (nixpkgs, macports, homebrew, etc etc) -- roll your own only if you have a very good reason not to take advantage of packages someone else built and maintains.

Thank you for all of your advice! I'm learning a lot. As you guys probably already noticed, I'm beginner haha so it might take a long time to fix it. But I'll try and study as you guys suggested. Thanks!
